# raspberry-pi - sensor details with Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, iot

Is it, in any way, possible to get a sensor details (e.g. manufacturer, type, model, function, etc.) using a raspberry pi?
Thanks.

Comment: Question is to broad. Need to be more specific: brand, model, function etc.

Comment: But this is what I am asking!! I really don't understand why you gave the question a bad review! If you don't know you don't know.
Let's say I have a RPi that has some sensors connected to it. I want to be able to discover them. Is there a way I can do this without the need for a manual pre-configuration.

Comment: There are thousand of different sensors you can plug into a RPI: from a simple on/off switch to a sophisticated 'smart' sensor. So, the answer will yes you can and no you can't; both answers are 100% correct. Unless you can physically identify the 'sensor', the question will be to broad and useless.

Comment: If you have any in mind, can you give me an example of a sensor that would allow me to do so? Thanks!

Comment: U need to specify how you are connecting the sensor to the board, is it via serial bus i2c, SPI or so or is it straight in to a Digital input pin. In any case no, you cannot get any information of the sensor ifself like this like you would get connecting to USB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible i guess. Because for getting information, that sensor details should be in the consideration of raspberry pi developers. you have to take a look into sensor datasheet

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if the sensor manufacturer has incorporated such functionality which allows the sensor to communicate its stored data via any communication protocol.

**Example - DS18B20.**

Each DS18B20 has a unique 64-bit serial code, which allows multiple DS18B20s to function on the same 1-Wire bus. The address is stored in the IC, therefore you have communicate and extract the address.

I have only tried this using C++. I looked up the web for [python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40378/ds18b20-address-finding).

So yeah, it depends on sensor rather then functionality of controller.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of sensor are you talking about? Temperature sensor, IR sensor?

What is the communication between the sensor and the raspberry pi? Is it via I2C or just an Analog read?

If the communication is done with more sophisticated communication such as Bluetooth or Wifi and has a protocol, then it may be able to query those sensor details

**TL;DR;**

Nope, Typically what the Rasberry PI sees the sensor is just a raw analog signal or a digital signal of the data. You would need the datasheet or manual of the sensors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I don't have a specific sensor in mind, nor a specific type of connection? What I am asking is, is it possible to do that? And of yes what are the options? What I am thinking of is, you have a raspberry pi or and arduino for example, you plug your sensor and you read some details about it, like manufacturer, type, model, etc. I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Yes and no, it depends on the sensor really.

Comment: Do you have an example of a temperature sensor that I can use for that purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @john, this might help, https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/TempSensor/CS

Comment: @KennyChan do not ask for details on your answer. they goes on comments